# Does Azure Data Factory's SalesForce connector support the TypeOf keyword in SOQL?

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory, soql

When I run the following SOQL statement against the SalesForce API, it works:

```
SELECT ID, TYPEOF ParentRecord WHEN WorkOrder THEN Case.CaseNumber ELSE NAME END FROM ServiceAppointment
```

The endpoint in Postman is:

```
{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/queryAll/?q=SELECT Id, TYPEOF ParentRecord WHEN WorkOrder THEN Case.CaseNumber ELSE Name END FROM ServiceAppointment
```

With results:
[image]

When running that from Azure Data Factory, there is a syntax error:

```
SOQL error: ... syntax error near 'SELECT ID, TYPEOF ParentRecord <<< ??? >>> WHEN
```

[image]

Does Azure Data Factory support the TypeOf keyword for SOQL?

Comment: what is the Salesforce API version you used while creating the linked service ? seems TYPEOF is available in API version 46.0 and later

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT Great question!  My SalesForce API version was set to default, so I changed it to explicitly be 52.0.  This is the same version I am using in Postman.  Same error in ADF.

Comment: oki, can you try using other `fieldList` or `what` ? Please share the complete error message you see and also snips from all your repro. [considerations for using TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm#:~:text=Note%20the%20following%20considerations%20for%20using%20TYPEOF%3A)

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT From your link, the following is what I am expecting is the issue: "TYPEOF can’t be used in SOQL used in Bulk API."  Thanks very much for the link.

Comment: Can you try removing `,` after `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to look for details on the error codes in specific but could not find much other than indicating server being less on RAM. However, the Salesforce connector is indeed built on REST and Bulk API, which is chosen automatically based on the data size (BULK api when result set is large) but as per your example it doesn't seem much.

Rest we can only assume as mentioned already in  [considerations for using TYPEOF](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm#:%7E:text=Note%20the%20following%20considerations%20for%20using%20TYPEOF%3A)

> "`TYPEOF can’t be used in SOQL used in Bulk API`".

I would suggest you raise a support ticket or log an issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues) or with `Salesforce` to get an official response.

Also checkout, [don’t use the Id field in a query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/big_object_querying.htm#:%7E:text=To%20retrieve%20a%20list%20of%20results%2C%20don%E2%80%99t%20use%20the%20Id%20field%20in%20a%20query)